# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a simple spring boot application from the STS starter project template.

So I create using the STS wizard as below:

`File->New->Spring Starter Project
                        * Type: Maven
                        * Packaging: jar
                        * Language: java *ver:1.8*
                        * Spring Boot version: 1.5.8
                        * Selected dependencies:
                            -> Actuator
                            -> JPA
                            -> H2
                            -> Web`

And this is my project structure after it finishes:

[image: Project structure]

Now I don't change anything in the project, I simply try to run the main class as a `Java Application` but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at io.yassir.springboot.SbCdCollectionApplication.main(SbCdCollectionApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

I have found other questions with the same issue, but none of the answers worked for me because I didn't even configure the project, it's spring's pre-configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by deleting maven local repository at `~\.m2\repository` and then re-setting eclipse configuration to default.

> This issue is caused by local jars being corrupted, or invalid eclipse build settings.